# Chrome extension. Debug background script through IDE

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, webstorm

I'm writing Chrome extension and want to debug background script and popup script through IDE (breakpoints, console, variables, etc.), not through Chrome DevTools. Is there a way to do this?

I can debug content script and options page because I can run it from IDE, but background script is launched by the browser.
I'm using Webstorm, but, I guess, other tools have the same issue.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear so it should be reopened. The solution in WebStorm is to create a new configuration in its `Run` menu from a template named `Attach`, and you should start your Chrome instance with `--remote-debugging-port=9229` command line where 9229 should be a unique unoccupied port.